# ReCAPTCHA BROWSER_ERROR occurs only when navigating to another page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha-enterprise

I have a Rails application using Google ReCAPTCHA Enterprise. I have gone through all the setup according to their documentation and it all works properly when I refresh the page immediately before submitting the form. However, if I navigate to the page from another page using `link_to` or some other turbo link, then when I try to create an assessment the following is true: `!response.token_properties.valid && response.token_properties.invalid_reason == :BROWSER_ERROR`

My assumption is that recaptcha does something special when you first load it that gets negated or otherwise undone once you navigate to another page. However, I can't seem to find any information about this in the documentation or other people complaining about the problem.

The following code describes how I am getting the token in the first place:

```
        const form = this
        if (!form.querySelector('[name=recaptcha]')) {
            event.preventDefault()
            const input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('name', 'recaptcha');
            input.setAttribute('value', JSON.stringify(await recaptcha(action)));
            input.classList.add('d-none')
            form.appendChild(input);
            form.querySelector('[type=submit]').click()
        }

...

export function recaptcha(action) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
      try {
        const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(document.getElementById('recaptcha-site-key').textContent, {action});
        resolve({token, action});
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

and the following describes how I am creating the assessment:

```
    client = ::Google::Cloud::RecaptchaEnterprise.recaptcha_enterprise_service do |config|
      credentials = SecretGetter.call(:recaptcha_credentials)
      config.credentials = JSON.parse(credentials)
    end

    request = {
      parent: "projects/#{Rails.application.config.x.recaptcha.project_id}",
      assessment: {
        event: {
          site_key: Rails.application.config.x.recaptcha.site_key,
          token: @token
        }
      }
    }

    response = client.create_assessment request
```

I don't suspect the way I'm creating the assessment is the problem because, again, it works as long as I refresh the page first. Probably the best way to solve this problem is to identify some recaptcha function that I need to call on turbo:load that will refresh the recaptcha and get it ready to respond.

Comment: I was really excited to see someone else had the same problem as me but disappointed to see no answers. I was about to comment and ask if you had figured this out since you posted, but then I realized you are me. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manually load the script on turbo load by hooking it into the connect method of one of my recaptcha controller. This allowed it to work even after clicking through a turbo link.

```
function loadScript(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = resolve;
        script.onerror = reject;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
}

export default class extends Controller {
    async connect() {
        await loadScript(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=${this.element.dataset.recaptchaSiteKey}`)
    }

    async submit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const action = event.target.dataset.recaptchaAction
        const recaptcha = JSON.stringify(await this.recaptcha(action))
        event.detail.fetchOptions.body.append('recaptcha', recaptcha)
        event.detail.resume()
    }

    recaptcha(action) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
                try {
                    const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(
                        this.element.dataset.recaptchaSiteKey, {action}
                    );
                    resolve({token, action})
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('error', error)
                    reject(error)
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```